# How to make a user create a record in draft state but not be able to view the created records?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

How to not allowing some users from seeing draft record and create record which by default be in draft state, can anyone help please , I have try this :

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="shipping_policy_cash_comp_rule">
    <field name="name">Shipping Policy multi-company</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_shipping_cash"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4.0, ref('custom_shipping.shipping_group_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('state','!=','draft')]</field>
</record>
<record model="ir.rule" id="shipping_policy_cash_comp_main_rule">
    <field name="name">Shipping Policy multi-company</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_shipping_cash"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4.0, ref('custom_shipping.shipping_group_main_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
</record>
```

[The Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwCcj.png)

Comment: Be clear and elaborate you question

Comment: how to make user create a record in draft and in same time not see draft records , odoo doing this if you can not see this state[draft] then you can not create record with state[draft] this is my problem , i hope it clear now . @Naveen

Comment: how to make user create a record in draft and in same time not see draft records?, is this even possible?@Salem Hassan

Comment: Yes its possible i can do it with PHP but i don't know if that possible in odoo that's why i am ask to figure it out if that possible or not . @Naveen

Comment: Check my answer@Salem Hassan

Comment: Is it ok?@Salem Hassan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this in your action:

```
<record id="any_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name"> Any Name</field>
        <field name="res_model">your.model</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state', '!=', 'draft')] </field>
</record>
```

or if you want this function to be applied only to a particular group means, write this in security.xml file:

```
<record id="your_id" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">Any Name</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model" />
            <field name="global" eval="False" />
            <field name="domain_force">[('state', '!=', 'draft')]
            </field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('the_module_name.group_of_that_user'))]" />
</record>
```

Comment: it hide from all , i have created two groups user and manager , i need user cant see and manager see now manager and user both not see the record in draft

Comment: Check now@SalemHassan

Comment: i think my odoo is cached

Comment: the changes not effected in my module i will create new database and see

Comment: its restrict me from creating a draft record again @Naveen

Comment: show me the restriction error screenshot@SalemHassan

Comment: see my post again the image link under the code part @Naveen

Comment: These type of errors pops only if you have given wrong csv info or wrong use of record rule@SalemHassan

Comment: i'am using the record you give me now and its same problem and i will show you my csv info now @Naveen

Comment: Show me the record rule and csv file@SalemHassan

Comment: this for manager group : access_shipping_cash_manager,shipping.cash manager,model_shipping_cash,shipping_group_manager,1,1,1,1
access_shipping_cash_line_manager,shipping.cash.line manager,model_shipping_cash_line,shipping_group_manager,1,1,1,1

and this for user group :
access_shipping_cash_user,shipping.cash user,model_shipping_cash,shipping_group_user,1,1,1,0
access_shipping_cash_line_user,shipping.cash.line user,model_shipping_cash_line,shipping_group_user,1,1,1,0

Comment: record role :
    <record model="ir.rule" id="shipping_policy_cash_comp_rule">
          <field name="name">Shipping Policy multi-company</field>
          <field name="model_id" ref="model_shipping_cash"/>
           <field name="global" eval="False" />
             <field name="domain_force">[('state', '!=', 'draft')]</field>
          <field name="groups" eval="[(4.0, ref('custom_shipping.shipping_group_user'))]"/>
      </record>

Comment: Yea i did from a long time.

Comment: Thank you for your help i appreciate it.